# Evaluating Limit with Trigonometric Integral Functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I am attempting to evaluate:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\bigl(\mathrm{Ci}(x) - \mathrm{Ci(3x)}\bigr)$$

Where $\mathrm{Ci}(x)$ is the Cosine Integral:

$$\mathrm{Ci}(x) = -\int_x^{\infty} \frac{\cos(t)}{t}dt$$

I want to use Frullani’s Integral indentity:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f(ax) - f(bx)}{x}dx = \ln\bigl(\frac{a}{b}\bigr)(f(\infty) - f(0))$$

I am aware that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \cos(x)$ does not exist, but upon typing the original limit I want into WA, it evaluates to $-\ln(3)$.
A bit puzzled and would like for  someone to show me how to specifically use that Frullani identity to solve this.

Comment: What is $\operatorname{Ci}(x)$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews [Cosine integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Cosine_integral) very probably.

Comment: Cosine Integral, I’ll edit it

Answer (score 3):

You can use the technique of Feynman parameters, introduce $\lambda>0$:

$I(\lambda) = \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x}\frac{\cos{3x}-\cos{x}}{x}dx$

$I'(\lambda) = -\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda x}(\cos{3x}-\cos{x})dx $

Using integration by parts, we can prove:

$I'(\lambda) = -\lambda\left(\frac{1}{\lambda^2+9}-\frac{1}{\lambda^2+1}\right)$

Now, integrating on $\lambda$:

$I(\lambda) = \frac12\left(\ln\left(\frac{\lambda^2+1}{\lambda^2+9}\right)\right) + c$

Our integral must vanish on the limit $\lambda \to \infty$, since the argument inside the logarithm in $I(\lambda)$ tends to 1 at infinity, we must have $c=0$. So, you can just substitute

$I(0) = \frac12\ln(1/9) = -\ln 3$

Comment: Clever! I didn’t think of trying a paramaterization like that. Could you perhaps try to utilize Frullani somehow? Solution is good I just want to know how to do it that specific way. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if a solution can be given on these lines. If I recall correctly, integrals of the form $\sin(x)/x$ and $\cos(x)/x$ are conditionally convergent, since Frullani applies to Lebesgue integrals, the conclusion you arrived at is essentially correct. What the Feynman parametrization does is some sort of "regularization", so that you can pick the finite part that arises at a suitable definition of integral.

Comment: I had recently tried taking the real part (with $a=-3i$ and $b=-i$) of $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{(e^{-x})^a - (e^{-x})^b}{x}dx$ and I got the answer using frullani that way, but I’m not sure if that’s allowed.